# Microsoft Teams - invoke HTTP request on message/reply in team channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-graph-teams

In MS Teams whenever someone replies to a message in a particular team channel, I want to invoke a HTTP request or publish a message to something like Azure Service Bus.

Is there a way to do this?

FWIW I'm trying to do 2-way SMS between a users mobile device and an agent using MS Teams. I'm using Azure Logic App(s) as the glue between the SMS provider and MS Teams, but the 1 part of the communication loop that I don't know how to handle is when the agent replies to messages in MS Teams. I know I can get messages via MS Graph API, but I don't really like this polling approach - I'd prefer more of an event based approach.

Answer (score 1):

Bartsch, currently we don't have any such event to trigger whenever someone replies to a message in a particular team channel. But have an option when a new channel message is added. As this feature is not available at present, could you please raise an [User Voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Comment: Thanks Jagadeesh. I raised this as an idea in user voice - see https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/43492746-ability-to-invoke-http-request-on-message-reply-in